# How should I understand the words 'hence' and 'also'?

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs

In this following context, how should I understand the words 'hence' and 'also'?

What does the word 'hence' refer to here?

How should I take this bold and italic part?

context:

> Here you will again remember that all the mental phenomena in one and
> the same state of consciousness, ***hence also impression (phassa) and
> feeling (vedanå),*** are necessarily dependent one upon another by
> their simultaneous arising, their presence, their association, etc.

Source: P. 36 "Fundamentals of Buddhism" by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Comment: Have you looked up "hence" in a dictionary? What definitions did you find? Which ones look like they fit here? What exactly are you unsure about?

Comment: It's not very well written. Better editing would be something like "mental phenomena in one and the same state of consciousness — including impression (phassa) and feeling (vedanå) — are necessarily …"

Comment: I think the author was trying to say that, because this relates to "all mental phenomena", it therefore (*hence*) also includes impression (phassa) and feeling (vedanå).

Comment: Thanks @ralph.m.